# Provide Kafka Client property at runtime to use kafka auth

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut

In the [micronaut-kafka](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/) documentation there is some info how to set custom properties. Via the `application.yml` file or directly using the annotation:

```
@KafkaClient(
    id="product-client",
    acks = KafkaClient.Acknowledge.ALL,
    properties = @Property(name = ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, value = "5")
)
public interface ProductClient {
    ...
}
```

I have to provide the `sasl.jaas.config` property at runtime, as the clients use authentication and the secrets are resolved on startup. After the secrets are resolved, the kafka consumer/producer should be initialised.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think micronaut have this setting in the current version.

But you can just add this row under your producer config in application.yml:

sasl.jaas.config: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required blablabla";

and read this via placeholder like:

Property(name = "sasl.jaas.config", value = "${kafka.producers.your_producer_id.sasl.jaas.config}")